# Why does loc / iloc selection return NaN rows?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a problem that is very frustrating to solve for.  I'm trying to use .loc to extract a subset of a dataframe since it is large and I want to reduce my memory demand.  The difficulty I am encountering is that non-selected rows are returning with NaN values.

It's particularly difficult to diagnose since its occurring in an async routine in Django, so it hasn't been throwing error messages.

As more detail, if new_df has 20,000 records, I am selecting the first 10,000 records on the first loop, and the second 10,000 on the second loop.  It runs "fine" for the first iteration, but on the second iteration, temp_df has len == 10,000 right after assignment, but somehow by the predict_proba line, temp_df.shape() shows 20,000 records, the first 10,000 of which contain NaN's.

Here is my code:

```
   iter_size = int(0.5*len(new_df))

    i = 0
    max_i = len(new_df)
    new_ests = np.zeros(max_i)
    while i < max_i:
        inds = list(range(i, min((i+iter_size), max_i)))
        if len(inds) == 0:
            break
        temp_df = new_df.loc[inds, :]
        temp_df = get_elixr_away(temp_df)
        temp_df = get_segment(temp_df)
        temp_df = get_segment_away(temp_df)
        temp_df['home_pb_lseason'] = 5700
        temp_df['net_pb_bseason'] = 0
        temp_df['net_exp_level'] = 0
        temp_df['net_level_gap'] = 0
        _, temp_df = add_trophs(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = add_segments_home(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = add_segments_away(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = add_elixir_home(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = add_elixir_away(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = code_features(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = code_away_features(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = code_home_features(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        temp_df = temp_df.loc[:, analysis_sel_cols]

        ests = (LR_MODEL.predict_proba(temp_df.loc[:, analysis_sel_cols])[:, pred_index])
        del temp_df
```

Unfortunately the NaN values are silently crashing my predict_proba calculation.

Since it's large, I've been deleting temp_df at the end of the loop, but this is not stopping the behaviour.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to use of slices to create the subset.  Still not clear why iloc or loc could not be used for this purpose.  Seems contrary to intentions.

```
    iter_size = int(0.5*len(new_df))

    i = 0
    max_i = len(new_df)
    new_ests = np.zeros(max_i)
    while i < max_i:
        inds = min((i+iter_size), max_i)
        if inds == 0:
            break
        temp_df = new_df[i:inds].reset_index()
        temp_df = get_elixr_away(temp_df)
        temp_df = get_segment(temp_df)
        temp_df = get_segment_away(temp_df)
        temp_df['home_pb_lseason'] = 5700
        temp_df['net_pb_bseason'] = 0
        temp_df['net_exp_level'] = 0
        temp_df['net_level_gap'] = 0
        _, temp_df = add_trophs(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = add_segments_home(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = add_segments_away(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = add_elixir_home(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = add_elixir_away(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = code_features(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = code_away_features(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        _, temp_df = code_home_features(temp_df, analysis_sel_cols)
        temp_df = temp_df.loc[:, analysis_sel_cols]

        ests = (LR_MODEL.predict_proba(temp_df.loc[:, analysis_sel_cols])[:, pred_index])
        new_ests[range(i, inds)] = ests

        del temp_df
```